# mean.io unit tests don't run

Tags: gulp, mocha.js, mean.io

Starting with a fresh mean.io app i.e.

```
mean init newApp
cd newApp
npm install [1]
bower install
```

[1] `npm install --dev` causes npm to run forever and eventually fail with an out of memory error, so I ran `npm install` followed by individually `npm install devPackage` for each package listed in `devDependencies`

The output for `gulp env:test mochaTest` is then

```
Invoking gulp - development
[10:12:54] Using gulpfile ~/projects/kueDemo/gulpfile.js
[10:12:54] Starting 'env:test'...
[10:12:54] Finished 'env:test' after 56 μs
[10:12:54] Starting 'loadTestSchema'...
[10:12:54] Finished 'loadTestSchema' after 487 ms
[10:12:54] Starting 'mochaTest'...


  0 passing (0ms)

[10:12:54] Finished 'mochaTest' after 48 ms
```

No tests are failing either and there are definitely plenty of tests to run in the Article package, so I don't see why they aren't being picked up.

*Note*: I have to CTRL-C to stop the gulp task and return to the prompt

The app itself runs fine out of the box. The Karma tests run fine if I run `gulp test` -- the mocha tests are still ignored.

System:

- node v0.12.2
- npm v2.7.4
- meanio v0.9.26

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after some debugging I found that this is a bug in the mean.io source.

in `gulp/test.js` the following lines should change:

Line 20:
    require('../node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/module/util').preload('../p

to

```
require('../node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/module/util').preload('./packages/**/server', 'model');
```

Similarly Line 24:

```
return gulp.src('../packages/**/server/tests/*.js', {read: false})
```

to

```
return gulp.src('./packages/**/server/tests/*.js', {read: false})
```

The `node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/module/util` preload function will now fail, but you can remedy this by patching the 2 realPath lines in the `walk` function:

```
// recursively walk modules path and callback for each file
function walk(wpath, type, excludeDir, callback) {
  // regex - any chars, then dash type, 's' is optional, with .js or .coffee extension, case-insensitive
  // e.g. articles-MODEL.js or mypackage-routes.coffee
  var rgx = new RegExp('(.*)-' + type + '(s?).(js|coffee)$', 'i');
  if (!fs.existsSync(wpath)) return;
  fs.readdirSync(wpath).forEach(function(file) {
    var newPath = path.join(wpath, file);
    var stat = fs.statSync(newPath);
    if (stat.isFile() && (rgx.test(file) || (baseRgx.test(file)) && ~newPath.indexOf(type))) {
      var realPath = fs.realpathSync(newPath);
      callback(realPath);
    } else if (stat.isDirectory() && file !== excludeDir && ~newPath.indexOf(type)) {
      walk(newPath, type, excludeDir, callback);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Created pull requests based on this: https://github.com/linnovate/meanio/pull/71    https://github.com/linnovate/mean/pull/1321